# Rspec giving false negative whilst testing pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, will-paginate

I'm writing a request spec, to test that **will_paginate** is working ok, and I've got a few problems. Firstly, here's a pruned version of my spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Articles" do

  subject { page }

  describe "index page" do

    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

    before { visit news_path }

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) } }
      after(:all) { Article.delete_all; User.delete_all }

      let(:first_page)  { Article.paginate(page: 1) }
      let(:second_page) { Article.paginate(page: 2) }

      it "should not list the second page of articles" do
        second_page.each do |article|
          page.should_not have_selector('li', text: article.title)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see there is a test to ensure that the second page of articles are not shown when the user visits the articles index page. This test fails:

```
1) Articles index page pagination should not list the second page of articles
   Failure/Error: page.should_not have_selector('li', text: article.title)
   expected css "li" with text "Article number 1" not to return anything
```

I can't understand why this is failing. When I manually create 31 articles, in development env, and view it in the browser, pagination works fine, but when I switch to the test env, the specs fail.

Article Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :title
  belongs_to :user

  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'created_at DESC'
end
```

Article Factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :article do
    sequence(:title)  { |n| "Article number #{n}" }
    body "This is the body"
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: ps - news_path maps to articles index

Comment: I suspect your factory to create the same article again and again, did you add a sequence?

Comment: i added my factory to the code, I don't think it's causing the problem.

Comment: how come you expect `"Article number 1"` NOT to be on the first page?

Comment: @apneadiving I have this in my model: `default_scope order: 'created_at DESC'` which should make the first article appear at the bottom of the list, and thus, on the second page

Comment: yeah, makes sense :) don't know then!

Comment: Do the results change if you change `let(:first_page)` to `let!(:first_page)`?

Comment: @zetetic, no that doesn't help, although I have fixed this issue. Will post my answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite incredibly, the solution to this was to do the following;

Change:

```
before(:all) { 31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) } }
```

to:

```
before do
  31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) }
  visit news_path
end
```

**Two things I learned here:**

1. The `before` block must not target `(:all)`, otherwise tests fail
2. I need to explicitly run `visit news_path` inside the before block, **after** the creation of the factories, otherwise capybara's page object will not be what I expect it to be

So, to illustrate:

This won't work:

```
# fails because it targets (:all)
before(:all) do
  31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) }
  visit news_path
end
```

And neither will this:

```
# fails because we are visiting the news path before the objects exist
before do
  visit news_path
  31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) }
end
```

It needs to be this:

```
# not targeting (:all) and only visiting news path after creation of the objects
before do
  31.times { FactoryGirl.create(:article, user: user) }
  visit news_path
end
```

Over 20 hours to figure this out, at least I learned some new stuff etc.